# Remote browser display on local machines

Tags: selenium-webdriver, virtual-machine, selenium-grid

I have a selenium grid set up on VM and am able to run tests on remote browsers. Now we have a requirement to see/view the browser instances which are running the tests remotely on VM. For this I need to display the remote browsers on local machines triggering the test runs. How can I achieve this?

We are looking for open source alternatives for team viewer where we can see the remote browsers.

Need something similar to www.browserstack.com.

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored using Chrome Remote Desktop as an option ?

Comment: yes , it requires some changes firewall settings which is not permitted.